# How to tell if a letter is a html entity?

Tags: php, html-entities

I'm confused about `HTML Entities`.

I'm getting data from a remote database. To store a `blank space`, the data team uses `ISO-8859-1 Symbols`. So a blank  is stored as `&nbsp;`.

Now, I'm querying this data, and, for some other reasons, I need to test if the returned character is a normal one or a Html entity.

My solution was to use `htmlspecialchars()`, like this :

```
$ch = '&nbsp;';

if(htmlspecialchars(' ') == $ch)
    echo 'same';
else
    echo 'not same';
```

This code will always returns `not same`!

**EDIT**

After reading the comments, I'll rephrase my question.

Given a string like this `123&nbsp;456`, visually, it will be interpreted as `123 456`. So, how could I tell if that blank is a `Space` or a `Non-breaking space`.

So, my question is: how to get the html entity of a blank space?

Comment: That's because the correct string would be `&nbsp;`, with a semicolon.

Comment: There is no HTML entity for a normal space. (At most there would be the numeric notation, but that’s not an entity.)

Comment: Also that ↑. `&nbsp;` isn't exactly a space. It's a non-breaking space.

Comment: @CBroe was alright https://eval.in/964495

Comment: @Phiter, that was a typo, sorry! But it's still `not same`.

Comment: Am I asking the wrong question or what ?

Comment: yes, its not the same. , for what reason is for what you want ?

Comment: No, your question has been answered, whether it was the right question, we wouldn't know :)

Comment: I've edited my question, would you please take a look..

Comment: just check that there is no usual space in the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use `htmlentities` instead of `htmlspecialchars` as that will match more characters, although that still wont match a space character as there is no html entity for space.

If you are looking to match non-breaking spaces, you could do:

```
if('&nbsp;' == $ch)
```